# No JDK Location settings/section in my android studio

Tags: java, react-native, android-studio

I have an issue when I want to build my react native app, it happens when I try to update my Jdk to latest version.. and I have download and install the latest version of Jdk, and I have set the JAVA_HOME as well and restart my computer to make it work.. but when I try to build my react native app, I have an error and it said "**The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe**",

after I do my own research, it needs to change my JDK location path in my android studio, but unfortunately, my android studio does not have JDK location section to change the path..

can anyone please help how to solve this issue...

Thankyou :)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti4d7.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of Android Studio you are using?

I'm using Android Studio Flamengo | 2021.2.1 Pacth 2.

[image]

In Android Studio, click on File and select Project Structure or simply use shortcut `CTRL+Alt+Shift+S`. A new window will pop-up. Choose SDK Location, then select Gradle Setting at the bottom. Click on the Gradle Jdk box and click Add. Now you can choose the location of the JDK that you have downloaded. I provide picture to facilitate understanding.

Hope that help.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.. my android studio is Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 version. I have followed yours and still not able to find that part..

Comment: Click File, then Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle you should see a jdk there. Set it to the one you want to use that is compatible with your project.

Comment: @fengelhardt Thanks for the answer, I also followed that step but still got nothing about JDK location..

Comment: Have you tried updating Android Studio?